# Getting form values from UIWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview, forms

In my iOS app, I have a UIWebView that can be passed in a html doc with a form containing an unknown number of fields.

If I know the id of the fields in the form, to pull the values into my application, I can go through them and call:

```
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementById('firstname').value"]
```

Is there a way to pull the list of all fields in the form so that I can iterate through it and pull all the values, or better yet, is there a better way to get access to the form data from my device?